# iPhone SDK: Pushed view controller does not appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios

I want to add a detail view for one of the cells in my `UITableView`. I've created a new view controller `SyncDetailViewController`) and a NIB for the detail view. Didn't make many changes in the new class. Just added a label and outlet for it and connected nib with view controller.

Now I've added this code to my view controller (the one with `UITableView`, not the new one)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SyncDetailViewController *dvController = [[SyncDetailViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"SyncDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
}
```

The problem is that even if I select any row in the `UITableView` nothing happens. It doesn't produce any errors or warnings. I've added a breakpoint inside this method and it is reached so this code is executed.

Any ideas are much apprieciated.

Comment: Is it sitting within a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nothing happens" sound so much like "sending a message to `nil`". Have you, by chance, checked that `self.navigationController` is not `nil`? Or that `dvController` is well initialized?

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. Thanks.